# Changing fill color in arrow shape?

Tags: smartdraw

I just installed SmartDraw, and can't figure out if it's possible to change the color used to fill an arrow shape :-/

The `Home > Shape Style > Fill` changes the whole rectangle instead of just the arrow itself:

[image]

Also, is there a way to go back to a regular menu bar instead of the ribbon thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Select (left-click) the arrow
- Right-click on the arrow
- Select "Ungroup Objects"
- Click OK on the "Separate Drawing" window
- Select the arrow again
- Now the Fill and Line will apply only to the arrow, not to the whole symbol (even though it had only 1 part, the arrow)

I don't know how to change the Ribbon bar back to a regular menu. It can be done in Word 2007 with an add-on. No idea if such an add-on exists also for SmartDraw.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably have better luck posting at the [SmartDraw support forums](http://forum.smartdraw.com/forums/11.aspx).

Comment: It doesn't look very active, but I'll wait and see. Thank you.